# array_unique возвращает массив больше, чем был подан на вход

Tags: php

Есть большой массив вида

```
$res_D = [
   ['domain' => 'example.com', 'data' => 'далее около 10 элементов'],
]
```

Выполняю следующий код:

```
echo PHP_EOL . 'Всего сайтов ' . count($res_D);
echo PHP_EOL . 'Всего column ' . count(array_column($res_D, 'domain'));
$domain_list = array_unique(array_column($res_D, 'domain')); // <- смотреть сюда
echo PHP_EOL . 'Уникальных сайтов ' . count($domain_list);
```

Получаю вывод:

```
Всего сайтов 104426
Всего column 104426
Уникальных сайтов 13096514
```

Вывод как array_column($res_D, 'domain'), так и $domain_list содержит примерно следующее:

```
[0=>example.com, 1=>test.com]
```

Флаги SORT_REGULAR и SORT_LOCALE_STRING пробовал.

Как array_unique можно отдавать более длинный массив, чем был подан на вход?
Руками массивы посмотреть нет возможности из-за слишком большой их длинны. Входных данных меньшей длинны ведет себя адекватно.

Comment: оффтоп, если выборка из БД, то лучше на стороне бд и посчитайте `count(distinct domain)`

Comment: а `count(array_flip(array_column($res_D, 'domain')))` что говорит?

Comment: Я понимаю, что этот вариант лучший. Но вынужден подерживать легаси код. По алгоритму потом считаются данные по всей выборке ($res_D).

Comment: Перевернутый массив говорит тоже самое.

Comment: Решил вопрос вот такой функцией https://pastebin.com/YLFFMRRh. Не знаю, что у PHP внутри, но поведение странноватое

Comment: а можете результат `array_column` скинуть в json куда нить, интересно что-то. на одной версии пхп проверяли?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с версией. На версии 7.1.26 (прод) как-раз баг и проявляется. На 7.3.4 и 7.1.22 (первые, что подвернулись под руку) все нормально. Странно это все.